# What is the smallest positive integer $t$ such that $t$ with $x^3_1+x^3_2+\,\ldots\,+x^3_t=2015^{2015}\,$

Tags: number-theory

What is the smallest positive integer $t$ such that there exist integers $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_t$ with  $$x^3_1+x^3_2+\,\ldots\,+x^3_t=2015^{2015}\,$$

this problem is Adaptation to me,Originally from the subject background [IMO shortlist 2002](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h17324p118686),

**the officia solution**:

> We prove that $t\leq 3$ is not satisfies. We have $$2002^{2002}\equiv 4^{2002}\equiv 4\pmod 9.$$Since $a^3\equiv -1,0,1\pmod 9$, hence $A=x^3_1+x^3_2+\,\ldots\,+x^3_t\not\equiv 4\pmod 9$ for $t\leq 3$. Let $t=4$. Then, by realizing that $2002=10^3+10^3+1+1$ and $2002^{2002}=2002^{673\cdot 3}\cdot 2002$, we have $$(10\cdot 2002^{667})^{3}+(10\cdot 2002^{667})^{3}+(2002^{667})^{3}+(2002^{667})^{3}= 2002^{2002}$$

But I take the same method,and $$2015^{2015}\equiv (-1)^{2015}=-1\pmod{9}$$
if $t=1$ .and it is clear $2015^{2015}$ is  not  cube number, so How to do this problem?

Comment: ...it is a cube.

Comment: @Wojowu,sorry ,I have  edit

Comment: Since your number is a cube, say $x^3$, you can write it as $x^3+0^3$.

Comment: @Wojowu,ok,if $2016$ replace $2015$

Comment: According to an answer at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/138886/which-integers-can-be-expressed-as-a-sum-of-three-cubes-in-infinitely-many-ways, it is believed that a number that is not 4 mod 9 can be expressed as the sum of 3 integer cubes. 2015 is 8 mod 9.

Comment: Correction: Integers that are not 4 or 5 mod 9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$3$ cubes are sufficient :

Take $$a=16\cdot 2015^{671}$$ 
$$b=78\cdot 2015^{671}$$ 
$$c=153\cdot 2015^{671}$$

Then, we have $$a^3+b^3+c^3=2015^{2015}$$

Beals conjecture (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beal_conjecture) has been proven for the case $x=y=3$ and $z=5$, so if a solution of

$$a^3+b^3=c^5$$ exists, then $a,b,c$ have a common prime factor.

Let $p$ be a prime factor of $a$ and $b$ and $v$ be the largest number with $p^v|a+b$. It is easy to show that $v$ is divisble by $3$. But for $2015^{2015}$ , this is impossible because for every prime, we either have $v=0$ or $v\ne 0\mod 3$.

Hence, two cubes are not sufficient. Hence, the smallest number is $3$.